# How can I trigger composed task runner through processor application in spring cloud data flow stream?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a requirement in which I have to trigger composed task runner (the logic of which is written in processor). How can I do this through stream?

Requirement :
I have to poll a particular directory, whenever there are 2 files present in that directory, my processor will decide that composed task runner should be launched or not. If yes, composed task runner will be launched with certain params and will process both files one by one.

Can anybody please help me in writing stream definition for this scenario?

Currently I am trying to trigger it like below:

`stream create exmaple --definition "triggertask --triggertask.uri=file:///Users/batch/apps/timestamp-task-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar --trigger.fixed-delay=30 | trigger-task-processor | tasklaunchrequest-transform --graph='xyz-d1 && xyz-d2' --increment-instance-enabled=true --spring.datasource.url=... --composed-task-arguments='some arguments' | taskLauncher"`

Where triggertask is trigger task source

trigger-task-processor is a processor which have business logic about trigger event)

tasklaunchrequest-transform is a processor(custom implementation of composed task runner)

taskLauncher is a task launcher local sink rabbit

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simplify your design using `tasklauncher-dataflow` sink application which acts as a REST client to SCDF server and issues the task launch request. You can launch your composed task this way.

In your case, you can have something like this:

```
file | tasklauncher-dataflow
```

The `file` is out of the box app and you can customize it based on your needs to send an output to the `tasklauncher-dataflow` sink.

You can find some of the references related to it as follows:

- https://content.pivotal.io/blog/need-24x7-etl-then-move-to-cloud-native-file-ingest-with-spring-cloud-data-flow
- https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/file-ingest/sftp-to-jdbc/
- https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-dataflow